# Visudo changes are not effective

Tags: debian, sudo

My original `/etc/sudoers` file:

```sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    
# Host alias specification
    
# User alias specification
    
# Cmnd alias specification
    
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
    
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
    
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:
zabbix ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: /home/server/systools/bin/zabbix/
    
    
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
wytools ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/server/wysystools/sbin/,/usr/bin/git
```

With these settings, `sudo` is not asking for a password. I tried to remove `NOPASSWD:` from the `%sudo` line with `visudo`, saved it, but changes are not effective (`sudo` still not asking for a password). How do I make changes effective?

Comment: Did you exit the editor?

Comment: Of course, just not rebooted (it's a live server, this is the last thing I want to try). It's running a pretty old Debian 7.

Comment: There is a group sudo and my actual user is in that group.

Comment: Changes are immediate. I would recommend keeping a root shell open when editing `/etc/sudoers` (`sudo  bash`, but don't use it unless you need to). Have you checked that the file has changed. Also check in `/etc/sudoers.d/`. There are fragments in there.